# What is a good Latex compiler for compiling Requirement Documents?

Tags: requirements

I'm searching a good Latex compiler for compiling Requirement Documents? Are there any compilers or plugins that support special tags for showing requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching for a package that provides macros and commands for writing documents with a certain structure / content. This has nothing to do with LaTeX compilers.

Usually, you have some template or other specification on how your document should be structured - there is no global, universally used standard on writing requirement documents. Even the definition of what exactly a *Requirement Document* is may vary. So it is very unlikely that there is a package that provides exactly the functionality you need.

This is a situation where you should write your own macros. You can e.g. define your own environment for a requirement, name it `requirement` and apply some styling and configuration on it. Consult [Customizing LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX) for a description on how to define own commands and environments.

If you plan to write multiple documents based on your macros, you may want to move them into a package. You can then use the package in multiple documents.